# jQuery AJAX cross domain issues

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json

I am having serious issues with trying to make an ajax call from my local computer(a regular index.html with main.js file) and from my own personal website. The ajax URL has a different domain and looks something like:

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    crossDomain: true,
    url: 'http://www.someURL.com/api/v1/comments/XXXXX',
    success: function(data){
        console.log(data);
    }
});
```

I have tried changing the type to JSONP, but then get an error "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token :". The ajax call is successful and not blocked, but the data is JSON. I tried working with CORS and asked a lot of my developer friends. I can't seem to get the answer, is it a problem with the database restricting me or what solutions do I have?

**Edit:**

I even tried setting an .htaccess file with:

```
# Always set these headers. 
Header add Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*" 
Header add Access-Control-Allow-Headers "origin, x-requested-with, content-type" 
Header add Access-Control-Allow-Methods "PUT, GET, POST, DELETE, OPTIONS" 
Header always set Access-Control-Max-Age "1000" 
Header always set Access-Control-Allow-Headers "x-requested-with, Content-Type, origin, authorization, accept, client-security-token"
```

**Error Received:**

> Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at someURL.com/api/v1/comments/XXXXXXXXXX. This can be fixed by moving the resource to the same domain or enabling CORS.

Comment: I even tried setting an .htaccess file with: # Always set these headers.
Header add Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
Header add Access-Control-Allow-Headers "origin, x-requested-with, content-type"
Header add Access-Control-Allow-Methods "PUT, GET, POST, DELETE, OPTIONS"
Header always set Access-Control-Max-Age "1000"
Header always set Access-Control-Allow-Headers "x-requested-with, Content-Type, origin, authorization, accept, client-security-token"

Comment: no database involved. Find out if api provides jsonp compatibility, because if not, no jsonp option would do the trick. Making CORS work is a real pain in the neck, so try to fix it via jsonp if posible.

Comment: What error do you have with this code ?

Comment: @Magus Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at http://www.someURL.com/api/v1/comments/XXXXXXXXXX. This can be fixed by moving the resource to the same domain or enabling CORS.

Comment: @monxas so it has something to do with the API settings and won't be able to be fixed through the frontend?

Comment: have you tried the option dataType: "jsonp"?

Comment: @Jamie I edited the contents of your two comments into your question. It's usually better to edit large details like error messages and what you tried via the `.htaccess` file into your question since it allows for additional formatting and helps to create a complete question with support information.

Comment: @War10ck agreed - I couldnt figure out how to edit my large text. Thanks for doing that! I just figured it out.

Answer (score 0):

By default,the requests you make inside your LAN will get blocked by the browser. To unblock cross origin requests, you need to enable the CORS. You can use browser addons to get this job done.

Here is my favourite one for chrome: https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/allow-control-allow-origi/nlfbmbojpeacfghkpbjhddihlkkiljbi?hl=en

After adding this extention, open the URL from where you are sending the AJAX call and use the above addon to enable CORS request.